# building user-based collaborative filtering system in Django

Tags: python, django, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I'm trying to build a simple `user based collaborative filtering` in `Django` for an `E-commerce` using just the purchase history. 
Here are the steps I use, I know it needs more improvements but I've no idea what's the next move.

here's the product model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
```

here's the purcashe model

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purchase_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now to get similar users

```
def find_similar_users(user, k=5):
    all_users = User.objects.exclude(id=user.id)
    similarities = [(other_user, jaccard_similarity(user, other_user)) for other_user in all_users]
    similarities.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return [user_similarity[0] for user_similarity in similarities[:k]]
```

and to calculate similarity between each:

```
def jaccard_similarity(user1, user2):
    user1_purchases = set(Purchase.objects.filter(user=user1).values_list('product_id', flat=True))
    user2_purchases = set(Purchase.objects.filter(user=user2).values_list('product_id', flat=True))

    intersection = user1_purchases.intersection(user2_purchases)
    union = user1_purchases.union(user2_purchases)

    return len(intersection) / len(union) if len(union) > 0 else 0
```

now here's my entry function:

```
def recommend_products(user, k=5):
    similar_users = find_similar_users(user, k)
    recommended_products = set()

    for similar_user in similar_users:
        purchases = Purchase.objects.filter(user=similar_user).exclude(product__in=recommended_products)
        for purchase in purchases:
            recommended_products.add(purchase.product)

    return recommended_products
```

Now, obviously that'd be really slow, I was thinking of using a copy of the data in another `no-sql` database.

Now if user `A` purchase something, I copy the data to the other database, do the calculation and store the returned similar products "obviously using background service like celery" in the no-sql database, and just retrieve them later for user `A` if needed, is that the right approach?

Comment: How many users ? Have you installed django-debug-toolbar for displaying queries run ? Make a query in a forloop is basically a bad idea in most of cases

Comment: @LucasGrugru it'll be a multi tenant project, will have many tables not just purchase so, yes, it'll be really bad

Comment: And saving a copy to be retrieved immediately is way better than calculating it each time

Comment: what you described does not involve making a query in a forloop at all. You do not resqpond about user count ? And about django debug toolbar ?

Comment: @LucasGrugru that's just the theory, I haven't applied the code yet, just thinking before doing it, I need a fast, editable approach that does not affect the normal application performance in anything so till now, copying the data to different db seems legit

Answer (score 1):

You can boost efficency a lot with:

```
def find_similar_users(user, k=5):
    all_users = User.objects.exclude(id=user.id).prefetch_related('purchase_set')
    similarities = [
        (other_user, jaccard_similarity(user, other_user))
        for other_user in all_users
    ]


def jaccard_similarity(user1, user2):
    user1_purchases = {
        purchase.product_id for purchase in user1.purchase_set.all()
    }
    user1_purchases = {
        purchase.product_id for purchase in user2.purchase_set.all()
    }

    intersection = user1_purchases.intersection(user2_purchases)
    union = user1_purchases.union(user2_purchases)

    return len(intersection) / len(union) if len(union) > 0 else 0
```

This will retrieve all `Purchase`s in "bulk" and thus only make two queries, which is probably where the bottleneck is anyway.

Comment: Agree, that's was just a theory code, the project is using multi tenant architecture so I need something faster without being calculated every time, Thought copying the data to different db would be great as the result will be stored there and retrieved later immediately instead of doing the calculations as it won't be just about purchase, it'll be about visits, wishlist, rating, cart...etc